# Combining datetime and timezone columns to get a date time object

Tags: r, datetime, timezone

I have two columns in my data set: DATE_TIME and TZ, which are both strings. I'd like to combine these two to get a proper data object.

```
> df
        DATE_TIME TIME_ZONE
1  4/18/1950 0130       CST
2  4/18/1950 0145       CST
3  2/20/1951 1600       CST
4   6/8/1951 0900       CST
5 11/15/1951 1500       CST
6 11/15/1951 2000       CST
```

This is what I tried, but which doesn't give me the expected result:

```
convertToDateTime <- function(dtString, tz) {
  strptime(dtString, tz = tz, "%m/%d/%Y %H%M")
}

df$DATETIME <- Map(convertToDateTime, df$DATE_TIME, df$TIME_ZONE)
class(df$DATETIME) # -> list
```

Apparently, this map turning the result of convertToDateTime into a list. Should I use a different function?

**UPDATE:** Okay, that was showing off, my lack of R skils :(. Fixed it, based on LukeA's comment as follows:

```
convertToDateTime <- function(dtString, tz) {
  strftime(strptime(dtString, tz=tz, format="%m/%d/%Y %H%M"), tz=tz)
}

df$DATETIME <- mapply(convertToDateTime, df$DATE_TIME, df$TIME_ZONE)
```

Comment: Well, `?strptime` _"turns character representations into an object of class "POSIXlt""_, which is a list object. Depending on what you want, you could use `format`/`strftime` or `as.POSIXct`. You might also want to check out `mapply` instead of `Map`, because it offers an unlisting option `SIMPLIFY = TRUE`.

Comment: You don't need to specify `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` in `mapply` as it is the default. In other words `Map` equals `mapply(SIMPLIFY = F)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Indeed, updated the update =)

Comment: Careful - Time zone abbreviations can be ambiguous.  "CST" has 5 completely different meanings.  See [this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone_abbreviations).

Comment: Also - regarding your update - if you're saying you've fixed the problem then you should put that code in an answer.  You can indeed answer your own question, and that is encouraged as long as the question/answer pair might be useful for others who encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the update in my question. The problem is solved as follows:

```
convertToDateTime <- function(dtString, tz) {
  strftime(strptime(dtString, tz=tz, format="%m/%d/%Y %H%M"), tz=tz)
}

df$DATETIME <- mapply(convertToDateTime, df$DATE_TIME, df$TIME_ZONE)
```